# Whoosh: matching terms exactly

Tags: python, whoosh

If there a way using Whoosh to return the documents that have a field matching exactly the terms in a query?

For example, say I have a schema that has a `autograph` field that has three possible values; `Autograph`, `Partial autograph`, and `No Autograph`. If I do a standard query `autograph:autograph`, I get all the records. Because the term `autograph` is in all records. I have tried doing something like `Term('autograph', 'autograph')` and applying that to the `filter` key word argument for the `search` function, but I end up getting the same results.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I have come up with a solution, It works.

First off, I redefined by schema so that autograph was an `ID` field in whoosh. Then I added a filter to the `search` call using a `Regex` query.

This works, but I am not going to accept it as the answer in hopes that there is a more elegant solution for filtering results.